# TypeError: Cannot read property 'value' of undefined in Angular 7

Tags: angular7

I am new to Angular 7 and I'm creating a simple CRUD application, using reactive forms, based on this [tutorial](https://appdividend.com/2018/11/04/angular-7-crud-example-mean-stack-tutorial/) which uses the MEAN stack. I developed the form as the tutorial suggested, but I'm getting the following error:

> TypeError: cannot read value property.

Click [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PREHP.jpg) to see my full error stack trace

Listed below is my code:

```
<div class="form-group">
          <button (click)="addBusiness(person_name.value, business_name.value, business_gst_number.value)"
              [disabled]="angForm.pristine || angForm.invalid" 
              type="submit"
              class="btn btn-primary">
              Add Business
           </button>
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following the example you said, you had to add that piece of code to the previous code. Maybe that's what you are missing.

**Update:** 
I added that code in stackblitz and its working:

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-stack-55598617?file=src/app/app.component.html

Can you use stackblitz to reproduce your error?

Comment: I have added everything, i  just pasted part of the  code where error is showing

Comment: Updated the answer. Can you provide a stackblitz example of the error?

Comment: I found out the error, i didn't add reference to the form control for example `<input type="text" class="form-group" formControlName="person_name" #person_name>` i didn't add the reference variable which is denoting by  **#**